# JAVA UI ActionListener 2 consecutive click of buttons with if else statements

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

I'm trying to make a UI that has bin, dec, so on.. and every time it's clicked only appropriate numbers corresponding the number system can be clicked by the user or is displayed in the textField, like if the user clicks bin only 0 and 1 can be displayed on the textField.

I tried to use nested if else statements but it don't seem to work. Please help thank you.

Here is my code below:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;  
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;


public class Trial extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

private JTextField textField;
private JButton n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n0, add, subtract, multiply, divide, clear, backspace, bin, dec, oct, hex;
private JPanel panel, panel1, p;


public Trial(String str)
{

    super(str);
    setSize(300, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4));

    panel.add(n1 = new JButton("1"));
    panel.add(n2 = new JButton("2"));
    panel.add(n3 = new JButton("3"));
    panel.add(backspace = new JButton("C"));
    panel.add(n4 = new JButton("4"));
    panel.add(n5 = new JButton("5"));
    panel.add(n6 = new JButton("6"));
    panel.add(bin = new JButton("BIN"));
    panel.add(n7 = new JButton("7"));
    panel.add(n8 = new JButton("8"));
    panel.add(n9 = new JButton("9"));
    panel.add(dec = new JButton("DEC"));
    panel.add(add = new JButton("+"));
    panel.add(n0 = new JButton("0"));
    panel.add(subtract = new JButton("-"));
    panel.add(oct = new JButton("OCT"));
    panel.add(multiply = new JButton("*"));
    panel.add(clear = new JButton("AC"));
    panel.add(divide = new JButton("/"));
    panel.add(hex = new JButton("HEX"));



    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel1.add(textField = new JTextField(20));


    panel.setBounds(20,20,300,150);
    panel1.setBounds(0,0,300,20);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    n1.addActionListener(this);
    n2.addActionListener(this);
    n3.addActionListener(this);
    n4.addActionListener(this);
    n5.addActionListener(this);
    n6.addActionListener(this);
    n7.addActionListener(this);
    n8.addActionListener(this);
    n9.addActionListener(this);
    n0.addActionListener(this);
    add.addActionListener(this);
    subtract.addActionListener(this);
    multiply.addActionListener(this);
    divide.addActionListener(this);
    clear.addActionListener(this);
    backspace.addActionListener(this);
    bin.addActionListener(this);
    dec.addActionListener(this);
    oct.addActionListener(this);
    hex.addActionListener(this);


    setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getSource() == bin){
        if(event.getSource() == n1){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "1");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n0){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "0");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == add){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " + ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == subtract){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " - ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == multiply){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " * ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == divide){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " / ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == clear){
            textField.setText("");
        }
        else{
            textField.setText("");
        }
    }

    else if(event.getSource() == dec){
        if(event.getSource() == n1){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "1");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n2){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "2");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n3){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "3");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n4){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "4");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n5){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "5");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n6){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "6");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n7){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "7");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n8){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "8");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n9){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "9");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n0){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "0");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == add){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " + ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == subtract){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " - ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == multiply){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " * ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == divide){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " / ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == clear){
            textField.setText("");
        }
    }

}




public static void main(String [] args)
{
    new Trial("Le Frame");
}
```

}

The problem of the above code is it does not display any character at all in the textfield.

Here below is a snippet of the program:
  ![1]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Len.png)

Comment: Hint:  `pass = 1;   if(pass == 1){` that code makes 0 sense; you assign a value to that variable before checking it. It will always be 1.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can priovide a solution for you. The code snipplet you've posted here looks definitely wrong, but we cannot provide a solution without to see your complete code.

Comment: I second the call by @SergiyMedvynskyy for an MCVE. Having said that, it would probably be better to put the choices between numbering systems (hex, dec, binary etc.) into a button group of radio buttons. In the action listener for the numeric buttons, the code can check which of the numbering system button group buttons is selected.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy  Hello! Thank you for responding. I edited my codes presented here and I also added an image.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did consider radio buttons, but my main problem is that in my codes I use getSource to know what number system is clicked by the user and then proceed to another if statement wherein it is on the displaying of the numbers and operations on the text field and for that I need to use another getSource but I understand that an event has only 1 source. I am stuck here.

Comment: *"I edited my codes presented here"* It's not an MCVE if it includes every button, but no main method or imports. Please **read** the linked document & also read about the [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). The SSCCE is the same thing as an MCVE, but the linked page goes into more detail.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm sorry I don't know how to make it concise so now I just copy pasted my full codes.

Answer (score 1):

When `event.getSource() == bin` is true, none of the nested if statements can be true:
   `if(event.getSource() == n1){`

Also this if will always be true because the assignment statement
   `pass = 1; if(pass == 1){`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I already tried without pass  = 1 and if(pass ==1). But I think the problem is, and as you might have mentioned, is that an event can only have one source which contradicts what I am trying to do. Do you perhaps know any alternatives? please help. Thank youu

Answer (score 0):

Try repainting or revalidating after updating:

```
textField.repaint();
```

Or possibly:

```
textField.revalidate();
```

Check out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html

Comment: Hello! I kinda figured what the exact problem is now. I think it's on the getSource thing as in an event I think you can only have one source. Could you offer some alternatives please? Thank youu

Answer (score 0):

So, you need a separate variable to hold the current view type (binary/octal/decimal/hexal)

In your code it should looks like:

```
private static final int BINARY = 2; // probably use enum
private static final int OCTAL = 8; // probably use enum
private static final int DECIMAL = 10; // probably use enum
private JTextField textField;
private JButton n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n0, add, subtract, multiply, divide, clear, backspace, bin, dec, oct, hex;
private JPanel panel, panel1, p;
private int system = DECIMAL;

// initialization code

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getSource() == bin){
        system = BINARY;
    } else if (event.getSource() == dec) {
        system = DECIMAL;
    } // same for other systems.

    if (system == BINARY) {
        if(event.getSource() == n1){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "1");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n0){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "0");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == add){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " + ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == subtract){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " - ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == multiply){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " * ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == divide){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " / ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == clear){
            textField.setText("");
        }
    } else if (system == DECIMAL) {
        if(event.getSource() == n1){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "1");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n2){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "2");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n3){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "3");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n4){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "4");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n5){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "5");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n6){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "6");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n7){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "7");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n8){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "8");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n9){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "9");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == n0){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + "0");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == add){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " + ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == subtract){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " - ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == multiply){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " * ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == divide){
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + " / ");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == clear){
            textField.setText("");
        }
    } // same for other systems
}
```

Please note: it's better to provide separate handler for any button. For example you can do it using lambdas. In this case you don't need a huge if-else-if blocks